# flutter : provider is not updating UI and Not Clearing the variables

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, provider, flutter-provider

This is my Query provider
In this provider My data is not updating UI not clearing variable of this function clearRaisedQueryDetailsLoad()

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QueryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  //raised query details

  bool _isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad = false;

  bool get isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad => _isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad;
  List _raisedQueryDetailsData = [];

  List get raisedQueryDetailsData => _raisedQueryDetailsData;
  var _raisedQueryDetailsSubject = '';

  String get raisedQueryDetailsSubject => _raisedQueryDetailsSubject;
  var _raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl = '';

  String get raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl =>
      _raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl;
  var _raisedQueryDetailsStatus;

  dynamic get raisedQueryDetailsStatus => _raisedQueryDetailsStatus;

 void addIsRaisedQueryDetailsLoad(bool isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad1) async {
    _isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad = isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addRaisedQueryDetailsData(dynamic raisedQueryDetailsData1) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < raisedQueryDetailsData1["query_details"].length; i++) {
      _raisedQueryDetailsData.add(raisedQueryDetailsData1["query_details"][i]);
    }
    _raisedQueryDetailsSubject = raisedQueryDetailsData1["query_subject"];
    _raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl = raisedQueryDetailsData1["attachment_url"];
    _raisedQueryDetailsStatus = raisedQueryDetailsData1["query_status"];
    print("_raisedQueryDetailsData $_raisedQueryDetailsData");
    print("_raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl $_raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl");
    print("_raisedQueryDetailsStatus $_raisedQueryDetailsStatus");
    print("_raisedQueryDetailsData ${_raisedQueryDetailsData.runtimeType}");
    print("_raisedQueryDetailsData ${_raisedQueryDetailsData.length}");
    notifyListeners();
  }

  getRaisedQueryDetailsData() {
    return _raisedQueryDetailsData;
  }

  getRaisedQueryDetailsDataStatus() {
    return _raisedQueryDetailsStatus;
  }

  getRaisedQueryDetailsDataAttachment() {
    return _raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl;
  }

  getIsRaisedQueryDetailsLoad() {
    print(_isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad);
    return _isRaisedQueryDetailsLoad;
  }

  getIsRaisedQueryDetailsSubject() {
    return _raisedQueryDetailsSubject;
  }

 void clearRaisedQueryDetailsLoad() {
    print("clear");
    _raisedQueryDetailsStatus = null;
    _raisedQueryDetailsSubject = '';
    _raisedQueryDetailsAttachmentUrl = '';
    _raisedQueryDetailsData.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
queryProvider.clearRaisedQueryDetailsLoad(); // Here When I am calling this api fuction multiple time then my provider data is storing duplicate data(This function is bellow)
```

and second issue is when I am calling raisedQueryDetailsApiCalled() this function from a dialog box then My UI data is not changing

```
  QueryProvider queryProvider = QueryProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      queryProvider = Provider.of<QueryProvider>(context, listen: false);
    });
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(widget.queryData["id"]);
    raisedQueryDetailsApiCalled();
  }

  raisedQueryDetailsApiCalled() async {

    queryProvider.clearRaisedQueryDetailsLoad(); // Here When I am calling this api fuction multiple time then my provider data is storing duplicate data

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        queryProvider.addIsRaisedQueryDetailsLoad(true);
      });
    }
    apiManager.queryRaisedDetailsApi(context, widget.queryData["id"]).then(
      (val) {
        if (val["code"] == 200) {
          setState(() {
            queryProvider.addRaisedQueryDetailsData(val["data"]);
          });
        }
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            queryProvider.addIsRaisedQueryDetailsLoad(false);
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This is my UI code

```
queryProvider.getIsRaisedQueryDetailsLoad()
            ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ProductListSkeleton(),
                    ProductListSkeleton(),
                    ProductListSkeleton(),
                    ProductListSkeleton(),
                    ProductListSkeleton(),
                    ProductListSkeleton()
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : queryProvider1.getRaisedQueryDetailsData().length == 0
                ? Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [Text("Data not available")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      _bodyChat(queryProvider1),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: provider is no longer maintained since the release of riverpod. Therefore, I suggest to migrate to riverpod instead.

Comment: @john can I use older provider version

Answer (score 0):

Try using the getter methods you have already instead of the general methods and see how that works. And maybe for the widgets code try to make use of consumers.

[Consumer Class - provider library](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html)